# Laravel Routing space in parameters returns 404

Tags: php, routes, controllers, laravel

I have a action like the following in my controller (home)

```
public function action_test($keyword)
{
    echo $keyword;
}
```

it works fine when i pass parameter without space like the following

```
http://localhost/laravel/home/test/apple
```

but it gives 404 error when i pass argument with space like the following

```
http://localhost/laravel/home/test/green apple
```

it does not even works when the space is encoded

```
http://localhost/shop/public/home/test/green+apple
```

not even this

```
http://localhost/shop/public/home/test/green%20apple
```

can anybody please help me in this

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use http://localhost/shop/public/home/test/?keyword=green%20apple

Comment: For slugs, you should stick to the standard: underscores and hyphens. Perhaps removing the hyphen/underscore from ”$keyword` for processing would do the trick?

Comment: @crynobone thanks for your tip! its working when using as query string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your route with (:all) instead of (:any).

From the [Laravel](http://www.laravel.com/docs/routing#wildcards) docs:

- (:any) : Allowing a URI segment to be any alpha-numeric string
- (:all) : Catching the remaining URI without limitation

Your route could then look something like this:

```
Route::get('home/test/(:all?)', 'home@test');
```

More on that topic in the Laravel forum [here](http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=1636).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the thinking behind this behavior, but the (:any), (:num) and (:any?) will not take strings with spaces. If you would like to pass strings to your route you should use (:all).

Answer (score -1):

http://www.laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing
You must register your controller's route, like:
Route::controller('home');
And check your controller class name is Home_Controller, also extend Controller or Base_Controller class.